# How to record videos of my desktop as a .mp4 instead of a .webm file?

Tags: video, 22.04, desktop-recording

In Ubuntu 22.04 LTS you can record your desktop quite easily by pressing print screen clicking on the video camera icon, then pressing the red button (I'd screenshot it but I don't know how to screenshot a screenshot).

The thing is, the final video is saved as a .webm file which is not widely supported, I would prefer to save it as an .mp4 file by default.

Comment: Not possible but you can easily convert it.

Comment: :C that is an inconvenience

Comment: `ffmpeg` might be a good route to convert videos, but so far it's too slow for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recordings are saved in the webm format and unfortunately that is the only format it supports. It is not possible to amend even using dconf-editor.

However, the default media player that is preinstalled with Ubuntu does support the webm file format.

Reference:

- [Record Your Gnome Desktop in Ubuntu with built-in screen recorder](https://linuxhint.com/record-gnome-desktop-ubuntu/)

Comment: it does bbut it;s an issue when sharing files

Comment: Just about any web browser on just about any OS will support playback of `webm` files.

Answer (score 4):

you can use **simplescreenrecorder**, recording can be initiated by CTRL-R (or you can change the key binding)

the app is found in the repository simply run

```
sudo apt install simplescreenrecorder
```

[image]

it supports .mkv, .ogg, .mp4 and .webm

Comment: A heads up that this works only for X (not Wayland)